# PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget отразить по-горизонтали

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Ранее я обращался с вопросом: https://clck.ru/RaV2K

Мне бы хотелось иметь возможность отражать изображение виджета по-горизонтали, чтобы оно "смотрело" влево или вправо.

Как мне с помощью PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget.setStyleSheet реализовать эту идею? Если с помощью этого метода это невозможно, то что может послушить решением, кроме как использовать дубликат изображения с отражением по-горизонтали?

Пока у меня есть следующий отрезок кода, который задаёт параметры отображения виджета:

```
widget.setStyleSheet(".QWidget {border-image: url(image.png); background: transparent;}")
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что значит, "отражать изображение виджета по-горизонтали, чтобы оно "смотрело" влево или вправо.". Покажите на изображении что вы хотите получить. А также не забываете публиковать [mcve]

Comment: https://clck.ru/RaVY5 https://clck.ru/RaVYw

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, то мне кажется что вам надо подготовить нужные вам изображения, смотрящие влево и вправо. Если вы хотите использовать 3D-изображения, то это совсем другая история.